# UtilityBar error when deploying

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, deployment, lightning-apps, utility-bar

When I attempt to do a deployment I get the following error. I have googled this and I'm not finding much useful information. Let me know if I should paste any other information that will help with assessing the issue. I'm fairly new to coding in Salesforce so I don't know much about UtilityBar. I created an application that houses a competent for my form fields. I didn't even know some UtilityBar file was made.

Fund_UtilityBar | Lightning Page | 0 | 0 | Component [flexipage:filterListCard] attribute [filterName]: Error retrieving filter [All] for entity [Fund__c]

Component [flexipage:filterListCard] attribute [filterName]: Error retrieving filter [All] for entity [Fund__c]

Comment: Doesn't seem like a strictly UtilityBar related issue. I suggest you look into the value being passed into filterName attribute of filterListCard component/page.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into this same error tonight. "All" is the metadata API name for a ListView that exists in the source org on the Fund__c object. The listview has been selected as a filter for the flexipage "Fund_UtilityBar".

Add it to the package being deployed (or by hand to the target org) to resolve this error.